# Puppeteer Node.js Script on Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I have an app that uses `puppeteer` to scrape through a website (log in, book some reservations, log out). The app uses a `mongodb` database to get the data it needs to log in and book reservations, and then store new data based on its success in completing those tasks.

I need this app to run everyday (i.e. `5:00 AM` each day). I want to use `AWS` in order to automate this process instead of having to tell my own computer to run the app each day. I'd like to be able to use AWS to host my website, access my `mongodb` atlas database, and run my `node.js` script.

After some research it looks like AWS Lambda will be the simplest way to get my app online. I have already built the app so it executes on my local computer with a simple `node` `app.js` command. My question is how do I link/upload my node `index.js` file to Lambda. I selected a simple "hello world" framework and see where an `index.js` file on lambda has been created with an `exports.handler` function inside it.

Do I need to copy and paste my local `app.js` file (the one that runs the app) into this `index.js` file on Lambda (that's several hundred lines of code and it needs to access a `mongodb` atlas database), or can I put a line of code inside the Lambda `index.js` file to call my `app.js` file (after I upload it). If I can call `app.js` inside the `exports.handler`, then what line of code would I need?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking the CDK workshop on: https://cdkworkshop.com/. It is a short intro which also goes throught how to setup a small stack using lambda and apigateway. Going through it will probably answer many of the questions you have.